Add class on menu item when active
I want the menu to have a color when its active, I tried add isActive but then is displays on all the menus at the same time. I only want it on the one that is active.
<template v-for="item in menuData.menuItems">
<a
          :is="item.type"
          :href="item.url"
          :text="item.text"
          :class="{ active: isActive }">
        </a>
</template>

const MenuData = {
  menuItems: [
    {
      type: 'a',
      text: 'Link1',
      url: ``,
      classes: [],
isActive: true,
    },
    {
      type: 'a',
      text: 'Link2',
      url: ``,
      classes: [],
isActive: false,
    },
    {
      type: 'a',
      text: 'Link3',
      url: ``,
      classes: [],
isActive: false,
    },
  ],
}

Added isActive but the active class is on every link

Please show how you define and update isActive variable.

I don't see your isActive state anywhere. So you can start by adding it on the state.
For example:
<template>
    <!-- loop using the template syntax -->
  <template
    v-for="(item, index) in menuData.menuItems"
    :key="item."
    :is="item.type"
    :href="item.url"
    :text="item.text"
    :class="{ active: item.isActive }"
    @click.prevent="handleMenuActive(index)"
  >
  </template>
</template>

<script setup>
// import ref function to act as the state
import {ref} from 'vue'

// define the state
const menuData = ref({
  menuItems: [
    {
      type: 'a',
      text: 'Link1',
      url: ``,
      classes: [],
      isActive: true
    },
    {
      type: 'a',
      text: 'Link2',
      url: ``,
      classes: [],
      isActive: false
    },
    {
      type: 'a',
      text: 'Link3',
      url: ``,
      classes: [],
      isActive: false
    },
  ],
})

function handleMenuActive(idx) {
  menuData.value.menuItems.map((item, index) => {
    if (index === idx) {
      menuData.value.menuItems[index].isActive = true
    } else {
      menuData.value.menuItems[index].isActive = false;
    }
  })
}
</script>

<style scoped>
/* add active class */
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

The active class will be added depends on your isActive inside your state

Hi! This is not working for me :/ The first link have the active class, but the other ones don't get it when I press link 2 and link 3?

Well, of course, it's just an example. To handle change class you have to do another thing. I've update my example to do that

:class="activeItem === item ? 'activeClass' : 'notActiveClass' "

You should compare your item to something (for example the current url) to get its active status:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const MenuData = {
  menuItems: [
    {
      type: 'a',
      text: 'Link1',
      url: `a`,
      classes: [],
    },
    {
      type: 'a',
      text: 'Link2',
      url: `b`,
      classes: [],
    },
    {
      type: 'a',
      text: 'Link3',
      url: `c`,
      classes: [],
    },
  ],
}

const activeUrl = ref('a');

</script>

<template>
  <a v-for="item in MenuData.menuItems"
          @click.prevent="activeUrl = item.url"
          :is="item.type"
          :href="item.url"
          :text="item.text"
          :class="{ active: item.url === activeUrl }">
        </a>
</template>

